Does GNU Guile not have the vector->string function?
According to scheme.org Implementations GNU Guile supports the R6 and R7 versions of Scheme.  And the guile executable has command line arguments of "--r6rs" and "--r7rs". And the Guile website says

As the R7RS is a much less ambitious standard than the R6RS (see Guile
and Scheme), it is very easy for Guile to support. As such, Guile is a
fully conforming implementation of R7RS, with the exception of the
occasional bug and a couple of unimplemented features:

The R7RS specifies a syntax for reading circular data structures using
datum labels, such as #0=(1 2 3 . #0#). Guile’s reader does not
support this syntax currently; https://bugs.gnu.org/38236.
As with
R6RS, a number of lexical features of R7RS conflict with Guile’s
historical syntax. In addition to r6rs-hex-escapes and
hungry-eol-escapes (see Incompatibilities with the R6RS), the
r7rs-symbols reader feature needs to be explicitly enabled.


And the Index at scheme.org shows vector->string as part of R7RS small. However, when I run Guile with the --r7rs option, it doesn't recognize vector->string.
"Unbound variable: vector->string"
The same code works with MIT/GNU Scheme
(display (vector->string #(#\H #\i #\!)))  ; => "Hi!"


Apparently not. It's not listed in the Procedure Index

You could use (list->string (vector->list #(...)))

Thanks. You should put the Procedure Index comment as an answer and I will accept it. I guess an oversight in their attempt to implement S7RS small.

Did you import the (scheme base) library?

Their absence does seem to be an oversight in R7RS support, yes. Consider filing a bug report about it?
In the meantime, here's versions of string->vector and vector->string for Guile.
(use-modules (srfi srfi-43))

(define* (string->vector s #:optional (start 0) (end (string-length s)))
  (vector-unfold
   (lambda (i) (string-ref s (+ start i))) (- end start)))

(define* (vector->string v #:optional (start 0) (end (vector-length v)))
  (string-tabulate (lambda (i) (vector-ref v (+ start i))) (- end start)))

